# Can suggestions be added to Google Chrome's Developer Tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome, workflow, developer-tools

I like to code through Google Chrome's Developer Tools. The ability to make live edits fast and see how the changes affect my design is invaluable. One thing I would really like, however, is to quickly test different fonts on my website.

One thing that Developer Tools lets you do is write "font-family" + "tab", and now suggestions will come up such as "cursive", "monospace", "serif", "sans-serif", etc. I can use the arrow keys (up and down) to quickly alternate between these values and see how they affect my design. What would be much more powerful, however, would be the ability to use many of my system fonts. Manually writing these font-families is slow and definitely not an ideal workflow.

Chrome has this resource for hacking Developer Tools: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WNF-KqRSzPLUUfZqQG5AFeU_Ll8TfWYcJasa_XGf7ro/edit#heading=h.ttn690hlfupb

I looked through this, and I don't believe I was able to find something that would work for me. Does anyone know a way that this can be done though Developer Tools or even another method?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: @Paulie_D you didn't read the question. I am asking if anyone knows a method for adding font suggestions to DevTools. I am not asking for people to "suggest a book, tool, software library, tutorial"

Comment: It's the same thing...if it's not an option built in, you're asking for an off-site resource.

Comment: @Paulie_D that statement clearly means... don't ask for people to recommend any type of resource (book, tutorial, or other). I don't need a resource recommended. I provided one that I am trying to follow, but having a hard time understanding. I have seen this done on StackOverflow thousands of times.